Positive-semidefiniteness of complex Teoplitz Hermitian matrix and implications on its range space
I have a problem understanding one proof in this article (Theorem 6.3 p.31).
Let $x>0, \mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $\mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, and define
$$
T(\mathbf{u})=
\begin{bmatrix}u_1 &  u_2 & \cdots & u_n \\
u_2^* & u_1 & \cdots & u_{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
u_n^* & u_{n-1}^* & \cdots & u_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the associated Toeplitz matrix. We assume
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & \mathbf{z}^H \\
\mathbf{z} & T(\mathbf{u})
\end{bmatrix}\geq \mathbf{0}
$$
Is it obvious that therefore  $\mathbf{z}$ is in the range of $T(\mathbf{u})$? The way it is written in the paper seems more general, like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & \mathbf{z}^H \\
\mathbf{z} & \mathbf{A}
\end{bmatrix}\geq \mathbf{0}\textrm{ and } x>0\Rightarrow \mathbf{z}\textrm{ is in the range of }\mathbf{A}
$$
Is this true? My best attempt to prove this is to use Schur complement to have $\mathbf{A}-\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{z}\mathbf{z}^H\geq\mathbf{0}$ which is equivalent to
$$
\forall \mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbf{y}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}-\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{y}^H\mathbf{z}\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{y}\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \forall \mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}, \mathbf{y}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}-\frac{1}{x}\left|\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{y}\right|^2\geq 0
$$
Taking $\mathbf{y}\in\ker(\mathbf{A})$ leads $-\frac{1}{x}\left|\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{y}\right|^2\geq 0$ and therefore $\forall \mathbf{y}\in\ker(\mathbf{A})$ we have $\left|\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{y}\right|^2= 0$ meaning $\mathbf{z}\in\ker(\mathbf{A})^\perp$, but I'm not sure if I can conclude that therefore $\mathbf{z}$ is in the range of $\mathbf{A}$ (maybe the range and the kernel are not disjoint, so $\mathbf{z}$ might be neither in the kernel nor the range, isn't it?)
Thanks!
